# Codeigniter CSRF cookie issue with Chrome/IE

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm having an issue with Chrome/IE explorer for session cookies.

I have this:

```
$config['csrf_expire'] = 77200;
```

When the value is set this high, I am able to log in no problem using chrome or IE. 
This is what chrome's web kit returns for the cookie's expiration time:'

Date:Thu, 21 Feb 2013 15:47:27 GMT
Server:Apache
expires=Fri, 22-Feb-2013 13:14:07 GMT;

However, when the value is set lower such as:

```
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

The chrome webkit returns:

expires=Thu, 21-Feb-2013 17:51:26 GMT

As you can see, there is enough time before the cookie should expire, but it seems to be expiring instantly, so I'm unable to log in. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Other info: Using Codeigniter, the issue only arrived after moving to a new dev server ( rackspace cloud, Redhat). Only a few machines are effected i.e some users can log in just fine using chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Is the server time and timezone set correctly? Timezone of the affected clients different to server timezone since conversion?

Comment: The server date/time is correct. Its a strange issue, as any value set above 7200 for the csrf expiration time works i.e < 7200 doesn't work, but anything >7300 will.

Comment: is your cookie being set from a http or https domain ?